# add time of blank noise to an audio, superpowered

Tags: superpowered

is there any way to add a time of blank noise to an audio?

I want to add extra time to the end and to the start of the audio, in order to when this starts and ends, it won't do it suddenly

Comment: When using a `SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer` you can add seconds of silence at the beginning by using the constructor parameter `unsigned int negativeSeconds`. You need to use negative values with `setPosition` to position the player there.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding samples set to 0 would add silence. So, if you put these samples at the beginning these samples will be played first and you will hear nothing for a short time (corresponding to the number of samples which are 0).